# Remove XML Tag using linq c#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am having on xml from which i have to remove the one book detail

```
<Books>
  <bookdetail>
    <bookname>ThreeIdiot</bookname>
    <bookauthor>chetan bhagat</bookauthor>
    <bookid>idi001</bookid>
    <isavailable>true</isavailable>
    <subscribername>NA</subscribername>
  </bookdetail>
  <bookdetail>
    <bookname>Csharp</bookname>
    <bookauthor>Kanitker</bookauthor>
    <bookid>Cshar001</bookid>
    <isavailable>true</isavailable>
    <subscribername>NA</subscribername>
  </bookdetail>
  <bookdetail>
    <bookname>VBbasic</bookname>
    <bookauthor>Andrew Parker</bookauthor>
    <bookid>idi001</bookid>
    <isavailable>true</isavailable>
    <subscribername>NA</subscribername>
  </bookdetail>
</Books>
```

Now I have to remove the book detail with `bookid == Cshar001`,
Please let me know any Linq command using will search and remove only that tag from the XML.

Comment: Looks like this is a homework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`XNode.Remove()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnode.remove.aspx) method for that:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load("myfilename.xml");
var xElement = (
    from x in xDoc.Root.Elements("bookdetail")
    where x.Element("bookid").Value == "Cshar001"
    select x
    ).FirstOrDefault();
xElement.Remove();
xDoc.Save("myfilename.xml");
```

Comment: where x.Element("bookid") == "Cshar001" 
    select x  giving error on this line

Comment: Sorry about that, forgot the `.Value`.